# React : How to keep component's state after hiding it

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an issue on my react project:

I have some components in my app that are inside `display: none` divs. It is navigations tabs.

When I switch from `display: none` to `display: block` every component loose their state but weirdly gets it back when I perform `this.setState` on a completely different attribute

Do you have any idea what could cause this?

Here is a video of the problem: https://drive.google.com/open?id=12xcwZtBem7jkQa2obAcQAbl0UMOGPiLC

Do you have any idea what could I go to prevent this behavior?

Comment: I've seen {isOpen ? <div>...</div> : null} instead of the display none

Comment: @Srucco thanks a lot for the reply but i don't understand? You saw that on the video?

Comment: I've seen it in code somewhere. Actually, it'd be something like {this.state.isOpen? ...} or {this.props.isOpen?...} in the render part of the component. I'm new to react and so idk if it's best to do it (Or if it'll work at all), but it might be worth a shot. Post an example component if you can.